# Disabling NVIDIA 3D Vision stereo on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia

I am running Ubuntu version 12.04. I have the NVIDIA Quadro 1000M Graphics card installed.

When I try to hook up a second display to the laptop, I get the following error:

Display (ViewSonic VA2231 Series (CRT-0)) does not support NVIDIA 3D Vision stereo.

I have tried hooking 3 different monitors up to the laptop, and all gave me the same error. Obviously I need to tell NVIDIA not to use 3D vision stereo, but I'm unsure of how to do so.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/en/man1/nvidia-xconfig.1.html

I looked at that page, but when I tried to use the --no-allow-dfp-stereo option:

```
$ sudo nvidia-xconfig --no-allow-dfp-stereo
nvidia-xconfig: unrecognized option: "--no-allow-dfp-stereo"

Invalid commandline, please run `nvidia-xconfig --help` for usage information.
```

I also tried setting the --no-stereo option, but that cause my resolution to become extremely small and low quality on the main screen.

While I was installing Ubuntu, the second monitor was connected and was displaying as though the computer recognized it. However, after restarting the computer, the second monitor was no longer recognized. As such, this seems to be a configuration issue.

ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/1.0-8756/README/appendix-d.html

According to that link, stereo should be off by default.

Has anyone had this same problem? How was it solved? I have installed the nvidia-current and nvidia-settings packages, so I don't know why the no-allow-dfp-stereo option wouldn't be working.

Comment: Same issue here with debian. Did you ever solve the issue?

Comment: No, if I remember correctly I chose a different video card in the system BIOS. This was a couples years ago at this point though so I'm not certain

Answer (score 4):

You can try

`sudo nvidia-xconfig --stereo=0`

and then reboot the pc.